# Array.map rendering the given data twice in React-Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, rendering

I am having the array of data which is rendered using map in React Native.But the component is rendering the data twice throwing the exception

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Here is my code.

```
  const test = ["Test1","Test2","Test3" ]
```

```
<View>
 {test.map(item=><Text>{item}</Text> )}
</View>
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, your data is showing up twice? Can you show more relevant code. Also this is just a warning which can be fixed using a unique key.

Answer (score 1):

> **Warning**: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

As it says ... It's just a warning

That can be fixed adding some unique key to your `<Text>`

```
const test = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"];
<View>
  {test.map((item, index) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text> )}
</View>
```

Worth to mention that [using index as key is anti-pattern](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/using-index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-in-react-8e5db3aea3a9) in certain use cases.

With the sample you gave us, the data should only be printed once